# How to get 2 folders at same level into the same git repo

Tags: git

**I have two folders in my sge remote account I want to put under versionnning :**

```
/extern/save/me/ and 
/extern/work/me/
```

**What would be the best way to get both under the same git repo as simlink for one to the other doesn't work ?**

Should I add one of them with the .gitignore file e.g.

```
in /extern/save/me/.git/gitignore : 
/extern/work/me/!
```

(non ignore clause)

I am getting the hang of git and this might seems to be a newb question...

Comment: Or may be best to go for relative link ../../work/me/!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. What is content of this folders relative to your repo?

Comment: @Samusz Do you have a repository already? Do you want to track all files and subdirectories in these 2 directories?

Comment: @phd yes I want to track all files in these 2 directories and since they are at the same level of the hiearchy I was at a loss on how to do it best. For now, not repo exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a repository in `/extern`, add subdirectories `save/` and `work/`, and ignore everything else:

```
cd extern
git init
git add save work
echo '*
!save/
!save/*
!work/
!work/*' > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately as this is an account on a computing farm I don&#39;t have write access to root... Should I edit the question or is this a separate one ?

Comment: I think I've seen somewhere there's a way to get around that by changing the .git folder path.

Comment: You can have `.git/` directory anywhere you want by setting GIT_DIR env var: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITDIRcode.

Comment: And if you cannot put `.gitignore` in the root you can ignore files via `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` or `core.excludesFile`: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore